# Proving $AB$ as a subgroup if $A, B$ are subgroups where $b^{-1}Ab\subset A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $A<G,B<G$ such that $b^{-1}Ab\subset A, \forall b\in B.$  Show that $AB<G$

So because $b^{-1}Ab\subset{A}$, $b^{-1}a_1b=a_2$ for some $a_2\in A$.  Then $a_1b=ba_2$

Now, let $a_1b_1,a_2b_2 \in AB$.  Then $a_1b_1a_2b_2=a_1a_3b_1b_2 \in AB, $ for some $a_3 \in A$.

$e=ab(ab)^{-1}=ab(b\alpha)^{-1}=ab\alpha^{-1}b^{-1}\in AB$.  Therefore $(ab)^{-1}=\alpha^{-1}b^{-1}$ for $\alpha\in A$ and $\alpha^{1}b^{-1}\in AB$.  This makes $AB<G$.

EDIT:  I originally had two questions here, but I accidently deleted my question.  I want to know if this is proof of the statement above, or if more (or less) is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part seems good, but I'm not really understanding the last argument: $e=ee\in AB$ without any hassle. Moreover
$$(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}=(b^{-1}a^{-1}b)b^{-1}\in AB,$$
because $a^{-1}\in A$ and so $b^{-1}a^{-1}b\in A$.

---

There's a shorter way: $AB$ is obviously non empty. If $a_1,a_2\in A$ and $b_1,b_2$, then
$$
(a_1b_1)(a_2b_2)^{-1}=a_1b_1b_2^{-1}a_2^{-1}
$$
Set $b_3=b_1b_2^{-1}\in B$; then
$$
(a_1b_1)(a_2b_2)^{-1}=a_1(b_3a_2^{-1}b_3^{-1})b_3\in AB
$$
because $a_1(b_3a_2^{-1}b_3^{-1})\in A$.

Comment: Wait, how do you justify $b^{-1}a^{-1} = (b^{-1}ab)b^{-1}$ from $b^{-1}ab \in A$?

Comment: @sidht Oops, I forgot a “to $^{-1}$”.